# What happens if memory is leaking?

Tags: visual-c++, memory, memory-leaks, memory-management

What exactly is a ***memory leak***?

And how will it affect the system the program is running on?

Comment: It's at least an order of magnitude easier to not have leaks to begin with than to diagnose an existing leak.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When your process allocates memory from the OS on an ongoing basis, and never frees up any of it, you will eventually be using more memory than there is physically in the machine. At this point, the OS will first swap out to virtual memory (degrades performance) if it has any, and at some point your process will reach a point where the OS can no longer grant it more memory, because you've exceeded the maximum amount of addressable space (4GB on a 32bit OS).

There are basically two reasons this can happen: You've allocated memory and you've lost the pointer to it (it has become unreachable to your program), so you cannot free it any longer. That's what most people call a memory leak. Alternatively, you may just be allocating memory and never freeing it, because your program is lazy. that's not so much a leak, but in the end, the problems you get into are the same ones.

Answer (score 4):

A memory leak is when your code allocates memory and then loses track of it, including the ability to free it later.

In C, for example, this can be done with the simple sequence:

```
void *pointer = malloc (2718); // Alloc, store address in pointer.
pointer = malloc (31415);      // And again.
free (pointer);                // Only frees the second block.
```

The original block of memory is still allocated but, because `pointer` no longer points to it, you have no way to free it.

That sequence, on its own, isn't that bad (well, it *is* bad, but the effects may not be). It's usually when you do it repeatedly that problems occur. Such as in a loop, or in a function that's repeatedly called:

```
static char firstDigit (int val) {
    char *buff = malloc (100);      // Allocates.
    if (val < 0)
        val = -val;
    sprintf (buff, "%d", val);
    return buff[0];                 // But never frees.
}
```

Every time you call that function, you will leak the hundred bytes (plus any housekeeping information).

And, yes, memory leaks will affect other things. But the effects should be limited.

It will eventually affect the process that is leaking as it runs out of address space for allocating more objects. While that may not *necessarily* matter for short-lived processes, long-lived processes will eventually fail.

However, a decent operating system (and that includes Windows) will limit the resources that a single process can use, which will minimise the effects on *other* processes. Since modern environments disconnect virtual from physical memory, the only real effect that can be carried from process to process is if one tries to keep all its virtual memory resident in physical memory all the time, reducing the allocation of that physical memory to other processes.

But, even if a single process leaks gigabytes of memory, the memory itself won't be being used by the process (the crux of the leak is that the process has lost access to the memory). And, since it's not being used, the OS will almost certainly swap it out to disk and never have to bring it back into RAM again.

Of course, it uses up swap space and *that* may affect other processes but the amount of disk far outweighs the amount of physical RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Your program will eventually crash. If it does not crash itself, it will help other programs crash because of lack of memory.

Answer (score 1):

When you leak memory, it means that you are dynamically creating objects but are not destroying them.  If the leak is severe enough, your program will eventually run out of address space and future allocation attempts will fail (likely causing your application to terminate or crash, since if you are leaking memory, you probably aren't handling out of memory conditions very well either), or the OS will halt your process if it attempts to allocate too much memory.

Additionally, you have to remember that in C++, many objects have destructors:  when you fail to destroy a dynamically allocated object, its destructor will not be called.

Answer (score 1):

A memory leak is a situation when a program allocates dynamic memory and then loses all pointers to that memory, therefor it can neither address nor free it. memory remains marked as allocated, so it will never be returned when more memory is requested by the program.

The program will exhaust limited resources at some speed. Depending on the amount of memory and swap file this can cause either the program eventually getting "can't allocate memory" indication or the operating system running out of both physical memory and swap file and just any program getting "can't allocate memory" indication. The latter can have serious consequences on some operating systems - we sometimes see Windows XP completely falling apart with critical services malfunctioning severely once extreme memory consumption in one program exhausts all memory. If that happens the only way to fix the problem is to reboot the system.